# How to get the position of a row in an ordered table with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

I'm new in Hibernate and I'd like to have, in the result set, the position of a row in an ordered table.
Suppose I have a table like this:

```
---------------------------
RUNNERS
---------------------------
NAME | TIME OF ARRIVAL
John | 2018-02-05 21:27:10
Mike | 2018-02-05 21:27:15
Luke | 2018-02-05 21:28:19
---------------------------
```

I'd like to have the position of a runner, given the name, by a query.
So, if I want to query that table with "John", I want the result to be:

```
NAME | POSITION
John | 1
```

Since John has come first to the arrival (Mike - 2; Luke - 3)

Is it possibile with a Hibernate query (MySQL dialect)?
Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables are not ordered by design, so rows don't have positions.

If you want to store positions, you should add a specific column. Than you'll be able to know a position of any row as well as get rows in guaranteed order (using `ORDER BY`)

Comment: Time of arrival seems like a valid candidate

Comment: But why should I store the position, if I have the time of arrival?

Comment: If I want to get the first, I would do this query, using the column time of arrival: SELECT * FROM RUNNERS WHERE TIME_OF_ARRIVAL = (SELECT MAX(TIME_OF_ARRIVAL) FROM RUNNERS). But how can I get the number of position by the name of the runner?